# Is there a good cross-platform way to include external C++ libraries using CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, cross-platform, static-libraries

I am pretty new to cmake, but I am loving it so far with my test projects and can't wait to use it with my next real project.

I want to start using cmake with external libaries (interface, pdf, json libraries, etc.) but I'm a little confused with the best way to do this that would still allow the project to be cross platform.

For example lets use a library like wxWidgets which needs to be compiled on a per system basis (I know there is a cmake command for wxWidgets, but I'm just using it as an example).

Would it be better to require the user to include the compiled wxWidgets files in the source directory and then point to that in the CMakeLists.txt file, or would it be better to require them to set up a system variable pointing to wxWidgets install directory, and then point to *that* in the CMakeLists.txt file? Is there a way to include an automated library build command and I could just include the massive wxWidgets source? Or is there another solution that I am completely overlooking?

All of the above would probably work in some form, but with CMake being widely used, I'm curious how most people would handle this.

This is a question that's kind of hard to phrase in a google search, so sorry if it's already been asked.

Comment: [Probably related: CMake:How To Find Libraries](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries). Though I wouldn't call it "good" way.

Comment: @VTT I read that right before posting this. It says that if you are using a library that isn't acknowledged by cmake, then you should include the necessary files in a project subdirectory. This lead me to ask the question "What if I need to compile different library files for windows and linux?" so I posted this question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, many libraries already have a module within CMake that allows their files to be located by CMake. If this is the case, generally all they need is to locate the 'root' directory in which the external library is contained. This is the reason for the [CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html) variable, which is frequently specified on the command line. Eg:

```
 cmake . -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="<WxWidgetsRoot>"
```

On many systems (*nix and OSX), libraries and headers are installed into system paths, and CMake will locate these automatically, as these paths are searched by default. On Windows systems, usually `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` is used.

If your external project doesn't have a CMake script that locates its headers/libraries, you can write it yourself by creating a `Find<package>.cmake` file and putting it in your `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`. See [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html) for more detailed instructions.

As for distribution of your project dependencies, that's entirely up to you. Any of a) Requiring your users to obtain them manually, b) download them via a script, c) obtain them from your own source control (eg. git submodule) are possible choices, and there are probably more.

Comment: thanks, this fixes the linux/osx problem, but what would be the best option on windows where libraries could be installed god knows where? Would the user have to set up their own "Find<package>.cmake" files?

Comment: If you are implementing your own "Find" files, they would need to account for any platforms you want to support. For example, if you look in FindwxWidgets.cmake, you'll see there's lots of platform specific stuff in there for Windows vs Unix. However, the installation location of the root of the package (on the user's system) is done with `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`.